# Put buttons inside input box

Tags: html, css

What I have

```
<form class="input-group-1 well" id="spinner-form">
    <input id="input1" class="form-control" type="text">
    <a class="btn" id="up-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
    </span>
    <a class="btn" id="down-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" ></span>
    </a>
</form>
```

What it looks like:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

I use bootstrap, here are some overwritten styles

```
   <style>
        .input-group-1 {
            width: 300px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }
        a {
            color: #737577;
        }
    </style>
```

I'm not sure how to edit the css to get this, please help!!

Thanks

Comment: Edit what *css*?? You have provided none.

Comment: i'm using bootstrap, how do i overwrite it to get this?

Comment: What do these buttons do? It looks like you're creating a stylized number input (`<input type="number" />`)?

Comment: Maybe something like `margin-left: -10px` will help you. Please, provide a fiddle.

Comment: Use absolute positioning on the `<a>` elements so that they overlay the `<input>` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9cf5bkn/)

Here's the relevant CSS/HTML

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-stack">
    <input id="input1" class="form-control" type="text" />
    <a class="btn" id="up-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up">^</span>
    <a class="btn" id="down-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">v</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.input-stack {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.input-stack input {
    padding: 4px;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: solid 1px #999;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
a.btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#up-button {
    top: 2px;
}
#down-button {
    bottom: 2px;
}
```